# Error in dist folder when running Angular Universal app

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I am trying to run my angular app using Angular Universal. As soon as I get the message, `Compiled successfully`, I get this error:

{PATH} means my local path.

```
{PATH}\dist\entrycoord\server\main.js:138830
const hasNativeClosest = !!Element.prototype.closest;
                         ^

ReferenceError: Element is not defined
    at Module.NE80 ({PATH}\dist\app\server\main.js:138830:26)
    at __webpack_require__ ({PATH}\dist\app\server\main.js:26:30)
    at Module.ld3Y ({PATH}\dist\app\server\main.js:266706:93)
    at __webpack_require__ ({PATH}\dist\app\server\main.js:26:30)
    at Module.PCNd ({PATH}\dist\app\server\main.js:146047:79)
    at __webpack_require__ ({PATH}\dist\app\server\main.js:26:30)
    at Module.BLWB ({PATH}\dist\app\server\main.js:93214:79)
    at __webpack_require__ ({PATH}\dist\app\server\main.js:26:30)
    at Module.ZAI4 ({PATH}\dist\app\server\main.js:179707:77)
    at __webpack_require__ ({PATH}\dist\app\server\main.js:26:30)

A server error has occurred.
node exited with 1 code.
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:56770
```

I use the basic auto setup of Angular Universal. I tried to add a lot of stuff the `server.ts` file, but none of them helped.

`server.ts`:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node'

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine'
import * as express from 'express'
import * as path from 'path'

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server'
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common'
import * as fs from 'fs'
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
const domino = require('domino')

const templateA = fs.readFileSync(path.join('dist/browser', 'index.html')).toString()
const win = domino.createWindow(templateA)
win.Object = Object
win.Math = Math

global['window'] = win
global['document'] = win.document
global['branch'] = null
global['object'] = win.object
global['HTMLElement'] = win.HTMLElement
global['navigator'] = win.navigator
global['localStorage'] = localStorage

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
    const server = express()
    const distFolder = path.join(process.cwd(), 'dist/entrycoord/app')
    const indexHtml = fs.existsSync(path.join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index'

    // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
    server.engine(
        'html',
        ngExpressEngine({
            bootstrap: AppServerModule
        })
    )

    server.set('view engine', 'html')
    server.set('views', distFolder)

    // Example Express Rest API endpoints
    // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
    // Serve static files from /browser
    server.get(
        '*.*',
        express.static(distFolder, {
            maxAge: '1y'
        })
    )

    // All regular routes use the Universal engine
    server.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] })
    })

    return server
}

function run(): void {
    const port = process.env.PORT || 4000

    // Start up the Node server
    const server = app()
    server.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`)
    })
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main
const moduleFilename = (mainModule && mainModule.filename) || ''
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
    run()
}

export * from './src/main.server'
```

Scripts I ran from `package.json` file:

```
"dev:ssr": "ng run entrycoord:serve-ssr",
"serve:ssr": "node dist/entrycoord/server/main.js",
"build:ssr": "ng build --prod && ng run entrycoord:server:production",
```

And of course I have a long `angular.json` file. Most of it is just the pregenerated code.

Tha part of `main.js` where the problem appears:

```
/**
 * Polyfill for browsers without Element.closest.
 * @param {?} element
 * @param {?} selector
 * @return {?}
 */
function polyfillClosest(element, selector) {
    /** @type {?} */
    let curr = element;
    while (curr != null && !(curr instanceof Element && matches(curr, selector))) {
        curr = curr.parentNode;
    }
    return (/** @type {?} */ ((curr || null)));
}
/** @type {?} */
const hasNativeClosest = !!Element.prototype.closest;
```

Comment: Is it from your code or not? If not, try adding domino to `server.ts`

Comment: @David this is the error log of the code :(

Comment: @David I tried to use domino, but I got the same error.

Comment: Show your `server.ts` file maybe. And is the code being called from your code or not?

Comment: @David I have updated my question.

Comment: Can you add a `console.log('here')` just before requiring `domino` and tell us wether the console log appears before or after your error? Also, you could open your `server.js` file at line 138830 and try to see where the code comes from...

Comment: @David I tried to put it there but I couldn't see it. Then I tried to put it befoie the first line, but nothing. I have updated the question with that part of the `.js` file.

Comment: what is the type of `Element.prototype.closest`, is it boolean?

Comment: @David I don't think so.

Comment: Do you has tried check your nodejs version?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably find the polyfill code in the `cdk` module. The `polyfillClosest` function should be somewhere here:

/node_modules/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-a11y.umd.js

In my case, the `cdk` module was added when I added:

```
ng add @angular/material
```

In my `package.json` it added the following:

```
"@angular/cdk": "^11.2.10"
```

The code was slightly different from what you posted in that it does a check now on the `typeof Element`:

```
var hasNativeClosest = typeof Element != 'undefined' && !!Element.prototype.closest;
```

This problem was actually already fixed in version 10.1.3, as you can see [here](https://unpkg.com/browse/@angular/cdk@10.1.3/bundles/cdk-a11y.umd.js). Updating the cdk version should do the trick.